# URL Rewrite rule - subfolder to query string value

Tags: vb.net, url, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a rule the will take the subfolder from the URL and convert that to a query string value for example:

If I navigated to this URL: `http://www.example.com/myfolder`
I would like that to read `http://www.example.com/default.aspx?folder=myfolder`

This is where I'm up to:

```
<rule name="Rewrite Language">
  <match url="([a-z]{2})(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/default.aspx?code={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

but this doesn't return the full subfolder value. I'll be honest I've stole this from a similar issue from this site, and I must confess I really have no idea what it all means!

I might be approaching this in the wrong way, my issue is that I can't be sure what the subfolder will be as this is generated dynamically from a random 6 character alphanumeric value.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIS Manager has a GUI / wizard interface for creating the rules which I usually find quicker and easier than entering the rule into the web.config file manually. Worth checking out: `IIS Manager -> select your site / application -> URL Rewrite -> Add Rule(s)`.

I think the following rule will do the trick for you:

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?folder={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Basically, the "match url" is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) that is used to identify a part of the URL. In this case, it captures a group containing one or more characters (except for a /), with an optional / at the end of the URL. It will then rewrite the url to `default.aspx?folder=` followed by the value that was matched (`{R:1}` refers to the first captured group, which will contain the folder name).

This will work provided you only have a single subfolder name (not nested folders).

You could also add a second rule which works in the opposite direction, so browsing to `http://www.example.com/default.aspx?folder=myfolder` would result in the user seeing `http://www.example.com/myfolder`:

```
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^default\.aspx$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^folder=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I added this to my web.config between <system.webserver> tags and I got a 404 error. Also when trying to access the URL ReWrite GUI via IIS Manager it generates an error: There was an error while performing this operation. Details: Filename: \\?\c:\inetpub\wwwroot\lnk.qa\web.config. Error:

Comment: I must add I got the 404 error when navigating to http://www.example.co.uk/myfolder

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you... Maybe you have added it to your web.config file at the wrong level? My example should sit inside the following nesting: <configuration><system.webServer><rewrite><rules>

Comment: That's where I have it. the annoying thing is I've got it working in the dev environment IISEXPRESS but as soon as I publish to IIS7.5 with URL ReWrite Module 2.0 installed it stops working. Is there any alternatives to URL ReWrite where I can have my application capture the 404 error and handle it?

Comment: Hmm, not sure then I'm afraid - I've used rules like these in both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS7.5 (not express) with no issues so can't think why it would stop working in production.

Comment: Many thanks for you help Matt, do you know of any other methods that can end with the same result? I've tried capturing the error in application start events within the global.asax and again this works until I publish the site... thinking the webserver needs a kick up the backside!

Comment: I'll mark this as correct as I'm sure it's a server issue my end. after all they rules work in the DEV environment.

Comment: Thanks - yes sounds like there's something strange going on with your server as the rewrite should work fine, and capturing errors in Global.asax sounds sensible enough. If you can get the rewrite working, then I guess you wouldn't need to capture 404s for this anyway, since any string passed after the URL would arrive in the query string of default.aspx - so you could do your logic to check for existence on that page and handle it accordingly.