# URL Rewrite rule - subfolder to query string value (Part 2)

Tags: rest, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a question regarding to url rewrite in IIS. The question resembles [URL Rewrite rule - subfolder to query string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367019/url-rewrite-rule-subfolder-to-query-string-value) quite a bit, but I fail to tailor the answer to my needs.

We have a REST interface that has this structure:

http://rest.company.nl:8090/interface.svc/accountmanager?customer=TEST

Now we want to add a company subfolder to the url and use URL Rewrite to be able to use the same rest application for all companies. It should work like this:

- http://rest.company.nl:8090/interface.svc/company1/someresource?somequerystring
- ...
- http://rest.company.nl:8090/interface.svc/company9/someresource?somequerystring

Should map to

- http://rest.company.nl:8090/interface.svc/someresource?somequerystring&company=company1
- ...
- http://rest.company.nl:8090/interface.svc/someresource?somequerystring&company=company9

I have written the following rule in IIS Site (with **Append Query String** and **Log rewritten URL** both checked):

```
<rule name="Company specific REST" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*/interface.svc/*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://rest.company.nl:8090/interface.svc/{R:2}?company={R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    <conditions>
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference I understand that the match in the rule will be compared to the path of the url. Now my path contains a file (interface.svc) rather than a folder. Could this cause a problem?

The response I get when I enter a company specific URL is a 404 and there is no log that sheds some light.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue in your rule regular expression.

you could try to use the below rule:

```
<rule name="Company specific REST" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="interface.svc/(.*)/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://rest.company.nl:8090/interface.svc/{R:2}?company={R:1}&amp;{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    <conditions>
           <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

Comment: Hi Jalpa, I had to modify one line of your rule:    <action type="Rewrite" url="/interface.svc/{R:2}?company={R:1}&amp;{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" /> Apart from that, it worked like a charm. Thank you so much!